# How to change the clear colour in createjs

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm making a game in createjs, and I want to be able to add trails behind everything. I know that in LibGDX, you can do this by making the glClearColor translucent.

Does createjs actually clear the canvas itself? If so, how can I change what colour it clears it *with*? If this isn't possible, is there any way I can emulate the effect?